# Clarify how VisualStudio "PackageReference" works

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, packagereference

My test scenario using "PackageReference" mode:

Project A reference project B.
Project B use third party library installed via packagemanager.
The Third party library depends on other third party library (tpl2 for brevity).

I try to use tpl2 from A, does not work (Ok A does not reference tpl2).
But if i install at least one package on A (es. tpl3) then i can also use tpl2 from A without reference it.

I don't understand how this is possible, any clarification?

Answer (score -1):

Usually, if project B is introduced into project A and project B uses the third-party library tpl2, then project A can call the third-party library tpl2 at runtime. But there are two exceptions:

1. If the third-party library used in project B is used as non-public (internal) or private (private) members, then A project will not be able to call these members, because they will not be exposed in the public API of A project.
2. In addition, if the third-party library used in project B depends on other third-party libraries that do not exist in project A, then project A may have a missing dependency error when compiling. In this case, project A needs to install and reference all third-party libraries and their dependencies that project B depends on in order to compile and run successfully.

In both cases, the advantages of Visual Studio are very prominent. In a nutshell, when you install tpl3 in project A, it triggers Visual Studio's mechanism for automatically importing package dependencies, which brings in all missing transitive dependencies, including tpl2, and makes them available to project A.
Of course, I can only make these answers because of the limited information you provided. If you have more ideas please speak up, but you need to provide more complete information.